# Delphi FMX - Fast Report

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am using Delphi 11 and Fast Report 2.8 FMX and I am doing this simple test.

In a form I put a FDDBconnection, FDQuery connected to my firebird database. Also put a FrxReport and a FrDBDataSet.
I have created a simple report that shows data from my query "select price, cantidad from anytable"

When run the code below, the report is displayed correctly.

```
 FDQuery1.Active:=true;
 FrxReport1.ShowReport();
```

[image]

Now I need to change some values ​​before printing and I wrote the following code.

```
begin
 FDQuery1.Active:=true;
 FDQuery1.Edit;
 FDQuery1.FieldByName('cantidad').Value:=21;

 FrxReport1.ShowReport(); <--THIS LINE SHOW ERROR ON RUNTIME
end;
```

[image: Error on ShowReport line]

I have tried to capitalize or lower case the field name but with no positive results.
How can I change the value of the dataset without it failing?

Comment: Error states that FireDAC can't find a field name with the name that you specified. So make sure you are providing proper name of the field you are trying to edit. And if your database is made from multiple tables make sure you are trying to edit the right one.

Comment: And call `FDQuerty1.Post;` after setting the field's value

Comment: The problem was result, I put all query result into a MemTable , then I modify the value of record over TMemTable. Now it work